# \captionof in a box

Tags: errors, captions, boxes

Am I missing something obvious, or is `\captionof` not supposed to work in a `\makebox`? I have tried `\protect`, `\MakeRobustCommand`, among others.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\begin{document}
    \makebox{\captionof{figure}{X}}
\end{document}
```

I receive this error:

```
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.4     \makebox{\captionof{figure}{X}}
```

Comment: Maybe helpful https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/222516/124842.

Comment: You can place it in a `\parbox`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes which, in turn, I can wrap in a `\makebox`. Yes, that works, thank you :)

Comment: Yes you can.  Though I wonder what added benefit wrapping the `\parbox` in a `\makebox` provides that the bare `\parbox` does not?

Comment: You might find \abovecaptionskip=0pt useful.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I use a hacky combination of three boxes, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/367225/30810. If that could be simplified, I would like that, but I haven't found shorter a solution yet.

Comment: I see now... you are using a `\makebox` of specified zero width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\makebox` provides a horizontal box for content and therefore has difficulty coping with vertical content. In particular, `\captionof` eventually calls `\@makecaption` to set the actual caption. This starts and ends with vertical skips inserted via `\vskip \abovecaptionskip` and `\vskip \belowcaptionskip`. `\vskip`s within a `\makebox` causes the problem:

```
\hrulefill

\mbox{\vspace{10pt}}% Acceptable...

\hrulefill

\mbox{\vskip 10pt}% Problematic...

\hrulefill
```

The above code snippet highlights the background legwork performed by `\vspace` in order to accommodate for non-vertical-mode skipping.

On the other hand, `\parbox` (and `minipage`, say) provide the option to incorporate horizontal *and* vertical content. So, if you want to place `\captionof` in a box, place it in a box that can manage its content, like a `\parbox`.