# Restrict background color to varwidth's narrower width with adjustbox?

Tags: floats, adjustbox, varwidth

I want to wrap a frame, with background color, around each table, with its caption included within the frame. For the frame, I've adapted [Martin Scharrer's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/425146/7922) to "[Adding border around figure and caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425122/adding-border-around-figure-and-caption)," which uses an `adjustbox` environment with the `varwidth` key. The frame itself is perfect, particularly that the width of the box shrinks (from a max of `\textwidth`) to fit the table and caption.

However, when I add a `bgcolor` key to set a background color, the width of the background appears to be the entire `\textwidth`, but I want the color to remain within the bounds of the frame. I.e., I want the background to respect the narrower width that `varwidth` determined. (MWE and output follows.)

How do I do this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{adjustbox}{varwidth=\textwidth,padding=1em,frame=1pt,center,bgcolor=pink }
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|cc|}
            \hline
            x   &   y   \\
            a   &   b   \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Caption}
        \label{tab:my_label}
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

Following up on @jon's observation in a comment: It turns out that the scope of the background color's coverage depends on where in the list of key=value pairs `bgcolor` falls.

In the below, new graphic, I present three outcomes:

- `bgcolor` is in position #1 or #2 `(bgcolor=pink,varwidth=\textwidth,padding=1em,frame=0.4pt,center)` or `{varwidth=\textwidth,bgcolor=pink,padding=1em,frame=0.4pt,center}`
- `bgcolor` is in position #3 or #4 `{varwidth=\textwidth,padding=1em,bgcolor=pink,frame=0.4pt,center}` or `{varwidth=\textwidth,padding=1em,frame=0.4pt,bgcolor=pink,center}`
- `bgcolor` is in the last position `{varwidth=\textwidth,padding=1em,frame=0.4pt,center,bgcolor=pink}`

[image]

I couldn't find anything in the `adaptbox` documentation that explains that the order of `bgcolor` would matter. But the story one could tell that rationalizes the pattern above is:

- When `bgcolor` falls before `padding`, it applies to the innermost (pre-padding) content;
- When `bgcolor` falls after `padding`, it applies to the "padded"
  content;
- When `bgcolor` falls after `center`, it applies to the
  widest area, i.e., after the line has been filled to the margins on the right and left.

(It would be great if Martin Scharrer could weigh in here about exactly what's going on. )

Comment: Surprisingly, the order in which you put `bgcolor` seems to matter. Feature or bug?

Comment: @jon, astute observation! I get three different results depending on where I put `bgcolor`. The order that gives me what I want is: `varwidth=\textwidth,padding=1em,bgcolor=pink,frame=1pt,center`

Comment: I've updated the question to show explicitly the dependence on the order in which `bgcolor` appears of the scope of coverage of the background color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering my own question just in order to bring this question to closure. As commenter @jon astutely observed: It matters what the order of the key values is; specifically, where `bgcolor` falls in the list.

In my case, I needed the scope of the coverage of `bgcolor` to (a) include the region after the `padding` is applied but (b) before `center` is applied. Thus, either of the following two key=value orders works:

- `bgcolor` is in position #3 or #4 `{varwidth=\textwidth,padding=1em,bgcolor=pink,frame=0.4pt,center}` or `{varwidth=\textwidth,padding=1em,frame=0.4pt,bgcolor=pink,center}`

Although I didn't find the significance of the order of `bgcolor` to be documented in the `adjustbox` documentation, the author of `adjustbox`, Martin Scharrer, has [separately confirmed to me](https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/adjustbox/issues/11/scope-of-coverage-of-bgcolor-depends-on#comment-48181924) that this is a feature (not a bug):

> Hi, that is a feature. You can add other keys after the background color, like adding another frame or margin or rotation and then add another background if you want. This way you have the maximum freedom.

Answer (score 5):

This solution uses `varwidth` and `\fcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \fcolorbox{black}{pink}{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|cc|}
            \hline
            x   &   y   \\
            a   &   b   \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Caption}
        \label{tab:my_label}
    \end{varwidth}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: interesting solution that clearly works. I'm going to see what other solutions might come forward (including see new comment to original question, where just moving the location of `bgcolor` fixes the problem (for unknown reasons). I've upvoted you in the meantime.